# replace every thing with in small braket

Tags: php

Hi guys need some help i want to replace string between "(" and ")"

```
$str = 'ABC-DEF-(AKJ)-A-12';
```

Expected out put should be

```
$str = 'ABC-DEF-(XYZ)-A-12';
```

Comment: You are expected to make some attempt to solve your tasks/issues on your own before posting here. If you have already made an attempt at this, please include it in your question and describe what the result is and how it differs from what you want.  If you have not already made an attempt, you should do so now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
$str = 'ABC-DEF-(AKJ)-A-12';
echo preg_replace("/\([^)]+\)/","(XYZ)",$str);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/tVAc8)

Answer (score 1):

You should use [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to do that.

```
$replace=preg_replace("/(\(.*\))/m", "(XYZ)", $str);
```